# Webpack: pass current entry name into js?

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

For example we have multiple entries:

```
entry: {
    main:  "./app/entry.js",
    view:  "./app/entry.js",
},
```

how to pass current name (main or view) into entry.js?

Ideal solution will be something like this:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    '_ENTRY_': '[name]'
}),
```

like other config options can have, but of course DefinePlugin dont know how to process this...

Comment: is the output for your files you want to use it?

Comment: what i want to do is inside entry.js write:
if (_ENTRY_ == 'main') {do something;} else {do other thing;}

Comment: i updated my answer please read and tell me if it helped..

Answer (score 1):

If you're running the code inside Node.js then you can use [__filename](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_filename)
and [__dirname](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_dirname).

Webpack can mock them for non-Node.js environments.
Please see [Webpack Node configuration](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/)

```
node: {
  __filename: true,
  __dirname: true
}
```

In this case you can use *__filename* and *__dirname* globals as usually done in Node.js enviroments.

```
if(__filename.indexOf('index.js') != -1) {
    // Code here
}
```

> **node.__filename**
>
> **Default:** *"mock"*
>
> **Options:**
>
> - *true*: The filename of the input file relative to the context option.
> - *false*: The regular Node.js __filename behavior. The filename of the output file when run in a Node.js environment.
> - "mock": The fixed value "index.js".